# Apache vhost : redirect repeating pattern does not work using mod-rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I need to prevent a repetition that may occur on my website with Apache ModSec : I want to redirect this kind of link :

```
www.example.com/forbidden/forbidden/forbidden/forbidden/index.html?uid=Ys7RZ2RWjrRtTYDoG5cEQgAAAAI
```

... to this :

```
www.example.com/forbidden/index.html?uid=Ys7RZ2RWjrRtTYDoG5cEQgAAAAI
```

*note : the "forbidden" part can have many more repetitions*

Using RewriteMatch I wrote this logic :

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteRule     ^/forbidden(.*)index.html\?uid=(.*)$    /forbidden/index.html?uid=$2 [R,L]
```

But it does not work : I still get a 404 and i'm not rederected to the [www.example.com/forbidden/index.html?uid=Ys7RZ2RWjrRtTYDoG5cEQgAAAAI](http://www.example.com/forbidden/index.html?uid=Ys7RZ2RWjrRtTYDoG5cEQgAAAAI) endpoint.

Is the rewrite rule syntax valid for my use case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this link to redirect multiple repetitions of `/forbidden`:

```bash
RewriteRule ^/?(forbidden/){2,}(index\.html)$ /$1$2 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Note that you don't match query string in `RewriteRule` but in this case you don't even need to match specific query string since query string is automatically appended to the redirected URL.